# Integer ranges in C++ - what should I do while the standard's not there yet?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++17

I know that the C++ heavyweights are working on getting ranges into the language, or at least the standard library:

- [Eric Niebler discusses ranges on his blog](http://ericniebler.com/2014/11/07/ranges-concepts-and-the-future-of-the-standard-library/)
- [Interview with @BjarneStroustrup on his thoughts re C++17](http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/04/stroustrup-cpp17-interview)
- ISO C++ standards committee (SC 22) [proposal N4128](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html) by Niebler, Parent and Sutton

To be fair - I haven't read through the official suggestion. I'm just a humble C++ programmer who wants to use simple range functionality. What should I do *today* rather than after C++17 to use, say, simple integer ranges with strides? Of course my requirements may expand as I start actually using ranges, but I'm still not after the fancier stuff and all sorts of corner cases. I think.

On the more restrictive side, I am working with a somewhat old environment due to compatibility needs (CUDA), so I need something to use with GCC 4.9.3 and its corresponding standard library version, and also something I can use in GPU code (not necessarily the same library/headers, but hopefully the same).

Well, should I roll my own limited-functionality integer range type, waiting for the formalities to settle - or should I go for one of the more heavy-weight alternatives (Niebler's "Ranges v3", Boost irange, etc.)?

Comment: That sort of depends on what you want to be able to do. If you just need a range boost.range might suffice; if you want the full functionality you can just use the range library eric niebler wrote; it's on github.

Comment: @KlemensMorgenstern: Boost and CUDA don't live together too well, I would need to "extract" irange/range from Boost. It may or may not be difficult to do.

Comment: It's a header-only library, so go for it. I don't know CUDA but boost.range is compliant C++ Code.

Comment: What do you mean by integer range: you mean the range `[1,2,3,4,5,6)` and `[1,3,5,7)`?  (ie, a range of integers with a fixed stride between them).  Or something else?

Comment: @Yakk: I mean `for(auto i = i_start; i < i_end; i += i_stride) { ... }`

Comment: Boost has many ranges in the MPL (eg. `iterator_range` and `range_c` which can specify the underlying type as well, such as an `int`). Those may be useful to you for this.

Answer (score 3):

Writing a simple "index" -- an input iterator that stores a type `T` and returns a type `O=T` via copy -- is easy.

What I call an `index` is an iterator over things that support advancement and comparison (including other iterators and integer-like things), and returns a copy of the contained object when dereferenced.  It is also useful to generate ranges-over-iterators-into-ranges.

```
template<class T, class O=T>
struct index_t:
  std::iterator<
    std::input_iterator_tag,
    O, std::ptrdiff_t, O*, O
  >
{
  T t;
  explicit index_t(T&& tin):t(std::move(tin)){}
  explicit index_t(T const& tin):t(tin){}
  index_t()=default;
  index_t(index_t&&)=default;
  index_t(index_t const&)=default;
  index_t& operator=(index_t&&)=default;
  index_t& operator=(index_t const&)=default;

  O operator*()const{ return t; }
  O operator*(){ return t; }
  O const* operator->()const{ return &t; }
  O* operator->(){ return &t; }

  index_t& operator++(){ ++t; return *this; }
  index_t operator++(int){ auto r = *this; ++*this; return r; }

  friend bool operator==(index_t const& lhs, index_t const& rhs) {
    return lhs.t == rhs.t;
  }
  friend bool operator!=(index_t const& lhs, index_t const& rhs) { return !(lhs==rhs); }
};
template<class Scalar>
index_t<Scalar> index_to( Scalar s ) {
  return index_t<Scalar>(std::move(s));
}
```

or somesuch.  `index_t<int>` is a stride-less integer iterator.

If we want stride:

```
template<class T, class D=std::size_t>
struct strided {
  T t;
  D stride;
  strided( T tin, D sin ):t(std::move(tin)), stride(std::move(sin)) {}

  strided& operator++(){ t+=stride; return *this; }
  strided operator++(int){ auto r = *this; ++*this; return r; }
  operator T()&&{return std::move(t);}
  operator T() const &{return t;}

  friend bool operator==(strided const& lhs, strided const& rhs){
    return lhs.t == rhs.t;
  }
  friend bool operator!=(strided const& lhs, strided const& rhs) { return !(lhs==rhs); }
};

template<class T, class D=std::size_t>
using strided_index_t = index_t<strided<T,D>, T>;
```

Now you just gotta write `range_t<Iterator>` (begin, end, empty, front, back, constructors).

```
template<class T>
strided_index_t<T> strided_index_to( T t, std::size_t d ) {
  return strided_index_t<T>( {std::move(t), d} );
}
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b,e;
  using element_type = decltype( *std::declval<It>() );
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
  bool empty() const { return begin()==end(); }
  element_type front() const { return *begin(); }
  element_type back() const { return *std::prev(end()); }
};
template<class It>
range_t<It> range(It b, It e){
  return {std::move(b), std::move(e)};
}
```

now we can make our index range:

```
template<class Scalar>
range_t<index_t<Scalar>> index_range( Scalar b, Scalar e ) {
  return range( index_to(std::move(b)), index_to(std::move(e)) );
}
template<class Scalar>
range_t<strided_index_t<Scalar>> strided_index_range( Scalar b, Scalar e, std::size_t d ) {
  return range( strided_index_to(std::move(b), d), strided_index_to(std::move(e), d) );
}
```

And now we test:

```
for (int i : index_range(0, 10))
  std::cout << i << '\n';
for (int i : strided_index_range(0, 10, 2))
  std::cout << i << '\n';
```

Similar objects also exist in [`boost`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html) and other range-based libraries.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c75478bce02b87d)

As an aside,

```
for( auto it : index_to( begin(vec), end(vec) ) )
```

iterates over the iterators of `vec` in a range-based manner.  Writing

```
for( auto it : iterators_into(vec) )
```

is also easy.

Comment: Isn't `std::iterator` going to be removed from the standard?

Comment: @einpoklum Why do you think that?  It is merely a helper type that makes defining valid iterators a touch easier...

Comment: I think I read about it in some kind of C++17 status update. Never mind. Another point: Since D is saved in a variable, don't I risk having more assignments and reads of values than with the for loop?

Comment: @einpoklum Then write `template<class T, T stride> class fixed_stride` that hard-codes the stride, if you want hard-coded compile-time strides?  If you don't have hard-coded strides, but `stride` is clearly unchanged, the state of `stride` can be inlined to local and determined to be invariant and optimized out by a half-decent compiler.

Comment: We'll see. Thanks.

Comment: @Yakk, I remember something about that as well. I think it was included in a new batch of things to deprecate/remove, so maybe STL is behind it if I'm actually remembering correctly.

Comment: @Yakk, Thank you, it was p0174r0 where I saw it, and that probably came up on std-proposals.